# enable pinch to zoom in viewcontroller

Tags: ios

I want users to be able to use pinch to zoom in my app which uses Storyboard and programmatically generated buttons and labels to produce a View within a Viewcontroller. In the View's Attribute inspector I have checked both `User Interaction Enabled` and `Multiple Touch`. But no pinch to zoom seems to work.

The code which creates the important part of the View is as follows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSInteger xPipsOrigin = 0;
    NSInteger xPipsStep = 22.0;
    NSString* cards = @"AKQJT98765432";
    NSInteger yPipsOrigin = 100;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        xPipsOrigin = 0;
        xPipsStep = 22.0;
        xPipsStep = 34.0;

    }
    else{
        xPipsOrigin = 100;
        xPipsStep = 40.0;
    }
    NSInteger xPipsCurrent = xPipsOrigin;

    self.countCards = 0;

    self.cardList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    yPipsOrigin = 100;
    xPipsCurrent = xPipsOrigin;

    for( int x=0;x<[cards length]; x++ ){
        [cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)];
        UIButton *b= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        xPipsCurrent += xPipsStep;
        [b setTitle:[cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [b setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [b setFrame:CGRectMake(xPipsCurrent, yPipsOrigin, 20, 20)];
        [b setEnabled:YES];
        [b setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:b];
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(spadeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }

    xPipsCurrent = xPipsOrigin + xPipsStep/2;
    for( int x=0;x<[cards length]-1; x++ ){
        xPipsCurrent += xPipsStep;
        UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(  0, 0, 20, 20)];
        lab.text = @"\u2660";
        lab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        lab.center = CGPointMake(xPipsCurrent+10, yPipsOrigin+10);
        [self.view addSubview:lab];
    }

}
```

How can I enable Pinch to Zoom in this app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to enable pinch to zoom on a `UIView` you have to wrap it into a `UIScrollView` first

Comment: You dont "have to" but you definitely get a quick result by doing as you suggest. You might as well use a gesture recognizer and implement the zooming yourself.

Comment: Correct. Wrong use of the phrase "have to". I meant, as you said, that is an easy implementation.

Comment: I have attempted to "wrap it" into a ScrollView, by merely changing the `UIView`'s `Attributes Inspector`'s `Custom Class` to `UIScrollView`, and adding the following code to my `viewDidLoad`. I do notice that the screen now bounces a little when I scroll [no scroll is necessary really because the view contains all the objects], but there is no reaction to my pinch to move gesture. `UIScrollView* sc = (UIScrollView*)self.view;
    sc.contentSize = sc.bounds.size;`. What else is required, please?

Comment: You can easily do that via Interface Builder but not simply changing the Custom Class to `UIScrollView`. Instead you can, from the menu "Editor" choose the "Embed in" -> "Scroll View" on your main content View that you want to wrap in the `UIScrollView`. After this, I guess you should set the `delegate` of the `UIScrollView` to your `UIViewController` and then implement the method `viewForZoomingInScrollView:` returning your `UIView` object

Comment: Vik, I had some difficulty using the "Embed in" -> "Scroll View" option in StoryBoard because it is grayed out. Apparently it only works if you select some objects in the view, not the view itself. Your answer was good other than that. After all, though, I do not think I will use the pinch to zoom, but only use the scrollview, and will create the size I want in code, not enabling the user to adjust it, unless later users complain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you can use `User Interaction Enabled` and try do it that way, it'll be easier to add a `UIGestureRecogniser` to your `UIView`. That way it handles most of the setup code for you, and when it detects a pinch triggers a method.

#### Basic example in Objective-C:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

- (void)handlePinchGesture:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"Recieved pinch");

     UIPinchGestureRecognizer *senderGR  = (UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender;
     NSLog(@"Scale is: %f", senderGR.scale);
}
```

#### And in Swift:

```
let pinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePinchGesture(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)

func handlePinchGesture(sender:AnyObject) {
    print("Received pinch")
    let senderGR = sender as! UIPinchGestureRecognizer
    print("Scale is \(senderGR.scale)")
}
```

Comment: I attempted to edit your method, `   if ([senderGR state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [senderGR state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [senderGR view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[senderGR view] transform], [senderGR scale], [senderGR scale]);
        [senderGR setScale:1];
    }`. And the scale works fine, but how do I also allow a transform that simultaneously allows a re-anchoring of the screen so that the button in the upper left corner of the screen remains in the scene?

Comment: Not sure what you mean I'm afraid, are you attempting to relocate the view but maintain a button in the top corner? If so you can either reposition the button according to the new transform, or have it so that the button is actually on a different view layer to the one you're transforming.

Comment: Notice that in my code `yPipsOrigin` and `xPipsOrigin` are both initialized at 100 for the iPad. When I use just the pinch to zoom, the left/top-most button disappears off the upper left corner of the screen, making that button and the others near it inaccessible. Can I preserve the upper-left anchor position, somehow?